# Should a DAO extend a data object?

Tags: java, android, database, architecture, dao

I have a class called `Measurement` that is basically just a Plain Old Java Object with some members, and which implements the `Parcelable` interface for easy serialization.

I want to store the data from `Measurement` objects in a SQLite database. I need an easy way to pass around the data with an additional database ID. My first solution was to simply add a `public long id` member to the `Measurement` class. This works of course, but it feels like it then becomes coupled with the database, which doesn't really make sense - a `Measurement` can exist without a database, and is used in various places that have no concept of a database at all.

So, my next thought was to create some kind of `MeasurementDbEntry`, which would extend `Measurement` and add the `public long id`. This would then be used in the places where it is relevant to have a database id included. Is this a good design, or would it be better if the `MeasurementDbEntry` didn't extend `Measurement`, but rather had a `Measurement` member and a `id` member?

Also, in the question title I'm mentioning [Data Access Object (DAO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object), but I'm not sure if what I'm talking about here is really a DAO, since it doesn't really access the database itself (I'm using a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper` to do that)? It is simply a more database-specific representation of a `Measurement`. Would it be considered a DAO (and should I name my class `MeasurementDAO`)?

Answer (score 2):

You got it absolutely correct, It's always better to maintain `DBEntry DAO` as separate entity.

Lets think in terms of `memory`,
Suppose assume your class `Measurement` need to be saved in `Database` which needs `10` more additional properties in future but where as in real time you will not using them all over the app, then if you use same model for both then it's consuming some unused memory where ever you access that, clearly in that case creating separate entity is the obvious and well preferred solution.

Always design application for scalability, today `id` is the only property, tomorrow you may have to add some other additional properties only for saving only in `Database`. This design can be handy for you in future.

Comment: I'd be concerned about over-engineering the solution and introducing complexity that isn't actually needed.  Why fix a memory problem when you don't have a memory problem yet?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it

Answer (score 0):

My personal view - is the additional effort of maintaining a separate class (regardless of whether or not it uses inheritance or composition) worth it?  An ID property is just a property - I don't explicitly see it as coupling something to the database (it's not like you're pulling DB-related dependencies into your Measurement class).

If it were me, I'd just update the Measurement class - besides, if you're going to read/write it anywhere else, you'll probably need the ID anyway, which means you'll still be passing it all over the place and nothing will use the underlying Measurement class directly anyway.

And yes, I agree - the class that you're talking about doesn't sound like a DAO - more like a DTO.